# How to insert into after the last row in a table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

i have this table below named **roombooking**:
[image]

I wrote this code that inserts a new row into roombooking(dont mind the details, just the **hotelbookingID**):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(startdate date , enddate date,idForHotel integer)
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN


INSERT INTO roombooking("hotelbookingID","roomID","bookedforpersonID"
                                     ,checkin,checkout,rate)
                                SELECT rb."hotelbookingID", r."idRoom", p."idPerson"
                                ,startdate-integer'20', startdate-integer'10', rr.rate 
                                FROM(SELECT "hotelbookingID" FROM roombooking
                                    WHERE "hotelbookingID"=
                                    (select "hotelbookingID"
                                     from roombooking
                                    order by "hotelbookingID" desc 
                                    limit 1)+1) rb,
                                (SELECT "idRoom" FROM room 
                                WHERE "idHotel"=idForHotel) r ,
                                (SELECT "idPerson" FROM person
                                ORDER BY random()
                                LIMIT 1) p,
                                (SELECT rate FROM roomrate
                                WHERE "idHotel"=idForHotel) rr;
                         


 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The problem here is that i want to insert after the last row based on the last hotelbookingID(it is in asc order)

My function works but as i guess it cant find the last row ,in order to perform the insertion after . (I think that the problem can be spotted here :

```
SELECT "hotelbookingID" FROM roombooking
                                    WHERE "hotelbookingID"=
                                    (select "hotelbookingID"
                                     from roombooking
                                    order by "hotelbookingID" desc 
                                    limit 1)+1)
```

Any help would be valuable. Thank you.

Comment: There is no concept of "last" record in SQL.  In fact, SQL tables are modeled after _unordered_ sets.  Just do your insert and then if you want to view your data in a certain order use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Any approach that uses a subquery to find the maximum existing `id` is doomed to suffer from race conditions: if two such `INSERT`s are running concurrently, they will end up with the same number.

Use an identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE roombooking
   ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START 100000);
```

where 100000 is a value greater than the maximum `id` in the table.

Then all you have to do is *not* insert anything into `id`, and the column will be populated automatically.

Comment: I created the identity column as you said and then i insert nothing on hotelbookingID but i get this error :   ERROR:  insert or update on table "roombooking" violates foreign key constraint "hotelbookingID_FK"

Comment: No idea - you never mentioned any foreign key. Perhaps you have to adapt something else to work with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

That `WHERE` condition makes no sense. There is no row in the `roombooking` table whose id is 1 + the largest id in the `roombooking` table.

You simply want to add 1 to the inserted value:

```
INSERT INTO roombooking("hotelbookingID", …)
SELECT rb."hotelbookingID" + 1, …
--                        ^^^^
FROM (
  SELECT "hotelbookingID"
  FROM roombooking
  ORDER BY "hotelbookingID" DESC
  LIMIT 1 
) rb,
…
```

That said, I would recommend to simply use a sequence instead (if you don't care about occasional gaps). If you really need a continuous numbering, I wouldn't use  `order by`+`limit` though. Just use an aggregate, and consider the case where the table is still empty:

```
INSERT INTO roombooking("hotelbookingID", …)
VALUES ( COALESCE((SELECT max("hotelbookingID") FROM roombooking), 0) + 1, …);
```

Comment: I did what you told me to ,using COALESCE in every select . But i get back this error:   ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: `MAX()` should only ever return a single row. Can you make a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13) with a complete example what you tried?

Comment: Sorry for taking your time . I will check it more carefully and then answer back to you.